# Is file() good for average of 5,000 - 6,000 lines or I must edit it for better performance?

Tags: php

The text file (from which my function grab info) is being recreated everyday at 00:00 and my application starts slowly during the day to add lines by lines as log file. The file is approximately 1 mb and with around 6,000 lines at the end of the day. So, it's not really small file. `The function is grabbing latest 21 lines from the text file to display latest 21 death/kills for a game and the script can be accessed by a lot of users to check the log statistics.` **My question is how I can make the script with better performance because `file()` is reading the whole file actually lines by lines, so what's a better way to do this? Can it affect the performance if a lot of people access the log page to display this info from the text file or for 6,000 lines, it should be all good ?**
The file is as plain text in .txt format and these are an example lines from the file:

```
1,42,16, 201,stackoverflow_user, 1, 6762160, 39799, 9817242, 6762160, 39884, 10010545,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1351147, 1165, 483259, 1351147, 1115, 241630, 0 
1,46,27, 201,[stackoverflow_user | stackoverflow_userother], 1, 4078465, 286991, 1594830, 4078465, 287036, 1643156,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1357147, 1115, 241630, 1357147, 1065, 120815, 0
```

**My function:**

```
# read a file into an array
$lines = file('C:/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

# flip our array over so the last lines of the file are first.
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
$n = 1;
$wanted = 21; # or however many lines you want.
$content = '';

foreach ($lines as $l) {
   # treat the data as comma-separated values
   $arr = explode(",", $l);
   # if col 5 has multiple values, take the first one
   if (preg_match("/\[(.+?) \|/", $arr[4], $matches)) {
       $arr[4] = $matches[1];
   }
   # is arr[4] the same as arr[12]?
   if ($arr[4] !== $arr[12]) {
       # these two are not equal, so use these values
       $data = array('rank-pos' => $n++, 'rank-name' => $arr[4], 'rank-dmuser' => $arr[12]);
       $content .= Template::Load('rankinguserdm-' . ($n % 2 == 1 ? 2 : 1), $data);
   }
   # have we got enough data?
   if ($n === $wanted) {
       break;
   }
}

        $this->content = Template::Load('user_rankingsdm', array('rankings' => $content));
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a database? SQLite comes immediately to mind …

Comment: I can't use database becuase the application is writing info to that text file and I must use the function to grab that info and display it on my website. Also, I am running on MSSQL Server 2005. So, as my question, is `file()` fine for that purpose (just my concern is if more people access the log statistics page to view the logs and hence overload the server?!) or maybe I must use `fopen` or something ?

Comment: You might be interested in reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741258/how-can-i-read-only-parts-of-text-file

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But you could write a simple service (run by a daemon e.g. all 30s) that reads the file and stores it in a database. And then your application reads from there with all its benefits.

Comment: So, it must reads it every second which will overload the database in that case ... at least affect it's performance ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a database can handle your requirements quite well and will not "overload". And they're a lot more scaleable than that file solution. ;-)

Comment: So, basically you say instead of reading the file and display ... it must read it every second and add data to the table ? I am using also MSSQL Server 2005

Comment: Using a database is *way* better option. Trust us, it can handle the load just fine. However, this question [nerd sniped](http://xkcd.com/356/) me. https://gist.github.com/Sammitch/7ff9c8486f8317666f4d

Comment: Okay, thanks. I understand. But simply, my question is even if I use the above function, will it realy affect the performance for small files like 1mb and around 6,000 lines ? Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, because you're reading in 5,979 useless lines as opposed to only the 21 you need.

Comment: So, will you be able to help me out tweak my current function to read only the latest lines? I will be so grateful to help me out. Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score -1):

if you are running on a unix system, think of calling tail

```
<?php
$file = log.txt;
$last_lines = `tail -n 21 $file`; // backticks indicate system call
print_r($last_lines);
```

Comment: I am running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. So, `tail` isn't option for me. :/

Comment: Can you use a windows equivalent?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command

Comment: I understand but will this have a better performance boost than `file()` when my files are approximately 1 mb in size with 5,000 - 6,000 lines?