# Is it possible to load a text file but only part of it with PHP?

Tags: php, text

I really have no idea what I am trying to say here but I have a 50Gb text file.
This PHP script I has filters the stuff in the text file. If I use the filter is opens
the WHOLE file and crash's my server. I have a different filter which somehow loads
part of the text file and filters it? It seems to be reading the file all the time.
Is this possible and what is it called? Thanks

Comment: use file handler's `fseek` and `fgets`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6733243/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/16741258/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was getting weird answers because I didnt search correctly.